# how to change color of single cell in gridview..?

Tags: datagridview

how to change color of single cell in gridview..?

```
protected void gv_transaction_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[6].Text == "Cancelled")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[6].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add detail what you want to do?

Comment: Do you want to change background color of the single cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Row.Cells[6].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```